# NextJS, preload Redux data in getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

Based on this [info](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) from the official NextJS docs they recommend using getServerSidedProps and getStaticProps instead of getInitialProps.

I want to preload some data to Redux state on the server.

**note**: I use @redux/toolkit package

So I have basic store setup:

```
import reducer from './reducer' // this is just a combineReducers ...
export const store = configureStore({ reducer });
```

My custom _app.js

```
import { store } from '../store'

<Provider store={store}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</Provider>
```

Now here is the issue I am facing

In the index.js file i have something like this

```
import { store } from '../store'
...
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const data = await fetchSomeData();
    // here I add some data to the store
    store.dispatch(someAction(data));
    return { props: {} }     
}
```

Data is set in the store while on the server side, however when I am on the client, store is empty. Does anyone know how can I preload data while on the server? I don't want to use useEffect of componentDidMount and set that data on the client. I know there is a library that is fixing this issue, but it is using getInitialProps instead, and I would like to see if something can be done in this way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`getServerSidedProps` should be used if you need the data only while you're server-side rendering. But if you need the data there for both cases when the user starts from this page (where you fetch data on the server) as well as client-side navigates to the page, it would be better to use `getInitialProps` to fetch data (via `redux-toolkit`'s `createAsyncThunk`).

Anyway, with both `getServerSidedProps` and `getInitialProps` you need to pass the server-side store to the to the client be the initial client store. You might want to consider using [next-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) for this task. You can find a nice [example here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper).

Furthermore, you're missing usage of `react-redux`'s `connect` to `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

I'm using `next.js` and `react-redux` with similar configuration to yours and I was struggling with all the boilerplate code required to get store data and dispatch actions. So I've created [connect-initial-props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-initial-props) to make it much easier to user `getInitialProps` to dispatch actions and consume state's data from redux store. You're welcome to take at the example on [connect-initial-props](https://github.com/webiya/connect-initial-props) Github.