# Using getStaticProps with next-redux-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I'm developing a simple next.js app. For state management I'm using next-redux-wrapper. In my home page I want to fetch all the rooms in my database from my api using `store.dispatch`.

When I use `getServerSideProps` and dispatch an action it works, it fetches all my rooms. But the problem is when I want to fetch rooms with `getStaticProps` it doesn't work nothing's happening.

Should I use next-redux-wrapper when I develop big apps or should I try other libraries. Because I want to use `getStaticPaths`, `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` in my app. And in theese functions I'm usually gonna dispatch an redux action.

Store.js File

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./reducers/reducers";

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
 const { composeWithDevTools } = require("redux-devtools-extension");
 return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
 }
 return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
 if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
 const nextState = {
 ...state,
 ...action.payload,
 };
 return nextState;
 } else {
 return reducers(state, action);
 }
};

const initStore = () => {
 return createStore(reducer, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]));
};

export const wrapper = createWrapper(initStore);
```

_app.js file

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { wrapper } from "../redux/store";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

pages/index.js file

```
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import { getRooms } from "../redux/actions/roomActions";
import { wrapper } from "../redux/store";

function HomePage() {
 return (
 <Layout>
 <Home />
 </Layout>
  );
}


//THIS WORKS
/*export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ req }) => {
      await store.dispatch(getRooms(req));
    }
);*/
// THIS WORKS


// THIS DOES NOT WORK
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(({ store }) => {
 async () => {
 await store.dispatch(getRooms("http://localhost:3000/"));
 };
});
// THIS DOES NOT WORK

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281070/nextjs-preload-redux-data-in-getserversideprops

Comment: @Ashok It didn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't be destructuring the `store` variable in the `wrapper.getStaticProps` call, should be `wrapper.getStaticProps((store) => {` instead just like you have in `wrapper.getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 7.0.x version.
`npm install next-redux-wrapper`, installs the 6.0.x by default

And this is supported only in 7 and above version of next-redux-wrapper