# Next js - access store outside react component

Tags: redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using getServerSideProps() for SSR in next.js and im trying to access the state in the getServerSideProps() function. But I can't use hooks outside of React components.

```
function Home({ products }) {
   return (
     {products.map(product => 
         <div>{product}</div>
     )}
   )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
  const { products } = productList

  return {props: products}
}
```

Comment: Correct, you can't. What is useSelector, can you share that code and more detail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS, preload Redux data in getServerSideProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281070/nextjs-preload-redux-data-in-getserversideprops)